# 20A or 30A fuse in 200A fuse clips -- is nesting reducers OK?

Tags: fuses, mechanical

So, I am trying to figure out the cleanest way to make a 20A or 30A tap from a 200A circuit (single hot + neutral) that is being run through a fusible safety switch (NEMA style, as this is in the USA), with power sources at both ends of the run.  So far, I have come up with the idea of using a 3-pole fusible switch with a solid neutral and wiring the switch according to the diagram below (neutrals not shown for clarity's sake):

[image]

However, this runs into a snag.  A 200A switch, of course, has 200A fuse clips in it, which are *far* too physically large to accept a 30A fuse.  Fuse reducer clips *are* a thing, but apparently, nobody makes a reducer that will take a set of 200A Class R fuse clips and adapt them for use with a 30A fuse.  Can I nest two sets of reducers (either 200A->60A and 60A->30A, or 200A->100A and 100A->30A) in order to achieve my goal?  Should I be looking to Class J fusing instead, where the desired reducer is available, albeit at an increased parts/availability cost?  Or am I better off using an appropriately sized fuse block mounted in the switch enclosure, separate from the switch's fuse clips?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will *work*, but whether it's recommended or even legal is another matter.

Comment: In general, I believe it is a code violation to use any wiring component in an a manner that is not approved. Approved uses are generally those that have been evaluated and listed by an independent testing laboratory. Wedging an appropriately sized fuse block into a fused-disconnect enclosure is also not likely an approved use. Using a fused disconnect as shown would also be questionable.

Comment: @CharlesCowie -- the use of the additional fuse block is permitted by NEC 312.8 provided the block itself is UL listed (not hard), it's just a bit of a hardware hassle compared to the alternatives.

Comment: What's your location? That would be helpful in determining whether or not this violates local code. Regardless of that, nested reducers wouldn't be my first choice. IMO reducers are only an acceptable solution if the alternative would be a major rewire. Nested reducers is just increasing trouble.

Comment: @Mast -- USA (as indicated in the question) -- assume that there are no significant local amendments to the NEC for the purposes of this question

Answer (score 1):

### Probably best to take another route

I spoke with a Cooper Bussmann tech support rep (via chat) and they recommended against it.  In my case, the alternatives include:

- Using a 30A fuse block with a suitable fuse and a 200A, Class R dummy fuse for the tap pole, which is probably the simplest approach as it allows the use of a fused switch, although it does introduce a (short) tap conductor into the circuit.
- Using field-fitted fuse blocks of the appropriate size to mount fuses in a nominally non-fused switch.  Again, this requires a short tap conductor, but allows more flexibility with fuse types (including the use of Class T fuses, which don't have reducers).
- Going to Class J fusing, as Mersen/Ferraz Shawmut makes a 200A->30A Class J reducer although it's not clearly a catalog item, and most North American fused disconnects can be reconfigured for Class J fuses simply by moving the load-side base to a different position.  While Class J fuses are more expensive than Class R or Class T fuses, this makes for a clean installation with no tap conductors roaming about or fuse blocks lurking in odd places.